# Angular get string instead HTTPReponse object

Tags: angular, angular-http

I have an issue because `err` is returning a string instead of a `HttpResponse`. I am not sure why, the server returns the content type as `"application/json"`.

Version of Angular is 13.

```
return this.http.delete(
  "http://Localhost:8080/delete",
  { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
).pipe(
  catchError((err, caught) => {
    return of(false); 
  }),
  map(() => {
    return true;
  })
)
```

I am not sure why doesn’t work

Comment: Please post properly formatted code. Currently it is very poorly formatted and have syntax issues.

Comment: Maybe you should post the error-response that your receive.

Answer (score 0):

You use RxJS first to catch any errors, throw away the actual error response, and return the boolean `false`. Then, if the request is successful, you are using RxJS to map that successful response, throw away the actual response, and return the boolean `true`. If you want an HTTP response, don't use the RxJS you've added in the `pipe()` operator. Handle errors and any other logic in your subscription instead.

Comment: Yes, but err is string not object

Comment: Then there's something wrong with your API.